# Data corrupting on program close in jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

Im using jxl to store data entered in by the user into an excel spreadsheet. I want to be able to close my program while its running and open up the excel spreadsheet and view the data. Whenever I do this, I get a message that says that it is in a different format than specified in the file extension. Here is my code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import jxl.*;                                                                    
import jxl.write.*;                                                              
import jxl.Workbook;                                                             
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;                                              
import jxl.write.Label;                                                          
import jxl.write.Number;                                                         
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;                                                  
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;                                               
import jxl.write.WriteException;                                                 
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;                                     

public class ReadWriteTest                                                       
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
    {                                         
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i = 1;

        Integer iAlliance = -1;

        File test = new File("C:\\test.xls");

        WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(test);

        while(iAlliance != 0 && i != 5)                           
        {   
            WritableSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet" + i, i);

            iAlliance = scan.nextInt();

            WriteExcel.addNumber(sheet, 0, 0, iAlliance);

            iAlliance = scan.nextInt();

            WriteExcel.addNumber(sheet, 1, 0, iAlliance);

            i++;
        }
        wb.write(); 
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"close my program while its running"

Your code needs to handle that.  Right now, it just gets killed at any point (probably in that loop), and nothing after that point happens.  The `WriteableWorkbook` never gets `write()` or `close()` called, and the file is probably corrupted.

So see this, try adding some simple output at various places, like "got to line number XXX".  Run it, close it, and see how far it got.

You'll probably need to wrap the bulk of your code in a `try-catch-finally`.  The loop is inside the `try`, the `catch` handles the lightning-out-of-the-blue program closing from that pesky human at the keyboard, and the `finally` closes up the workbook file properly.

Comment: The while loop doesn't throw an exception, so i can't put it in a try-catch-finally. The error is from whenever I open up the excel program.

Comment: @Praxton (1) You don't need to throw or handle an exception to take advantage of `finally` blocks.  (2) I didn't say the error message came from your program.  The underlying error is caused by a corrupt file, and the corrupt file is probably caused by the way your program exits.